# Unable to save objects using nested serializer in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have to save objects of two different models and using nested serializers. I am using following django rest docs:-
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#Writable%20nested%20serializers

I have followed many solutions on stackoverflow however I am unable to figure the following error:-

```
Bad Request: /api/register
"POST /api/register HTTP/1.1" 400 50
```

I checked my serializers by printing `request.data` and they are working fine. However, `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` raises the above error.

serializers.py

```
# Serializer for report

class ReportAPISerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    latitude = serializers.FloatField()
    longitude = serializers.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ('longitude', 'latitude', 'consumer_type', 'area', 'avg_monthly_bill',)


# Serializer to get user details

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property = ReportAPISerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = InterestedUser
        fields = ('full_name', 'phone_no', 'email', 'property')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        property_data = validated_data.pop('property')
        user = InterestedUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Property.objects.create(
            owner=user,
            location=Point(property_data['latitude'], property_data['longitude']),
            area=property_data['area'],
            consumer_type=property_data['consumer_type'],
            avg_monthly_bill=property_data['avg_monthly_bill']
        )
        return user
```

views.py

```
class RegisterAPIVIew(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

models.py

```
class InterestedUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    password = models.CharField(default="", max_length=128)
    is_superuser = None

    objects = InterestedUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s -- %s" % (self.full_name, self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.full_name:
            return self.full_name

        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active



class Property(models.Model):
    property_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    avg_monthly_bill = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    consumer_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
    area = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

Following code I am using on frontend side( usign Vue ):-

```
createAccount(fullName, email, phoneNo, latitude, longitude, area, consummerType, avgMonthlyBill){
    console.log(fullName + " ", email + " " + phoneNo + latitude + " " + longitude + " " + area + " " + consummerType + " " + avgMonthlyBill)
    let property = {
      'latitude':latitude,
      'longitude':longitude,
      'area':area,
      'consumer_type':consummerType,
      'avg_monthly_bill':avgMonthlyBill
    }
    return session.post('register', {
                                'full_name':fullName, 
                                'email':email, 
                                'phone_no':phoneNo, 
                                'property':property
                              });
  },
```

Comment: please add error  response in question

Comment: Can you clarify the error you've got? Just 400 isn't enough to understand the cause.

Comment: I am getting ```Bad Request: /api/register
"POST /api/register HTTP/1.1" 400 50``` as the only error response.

Comment: share how are you sending request to the API endpoint ?

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta added now

Comment: `is_valid` response contains validation errors so read them or share them here.

Comment: @IvanStarostin can you tell how to get response of ```is_valid```. I did ```print(serializer.is_valid()) ``` and got ```false``` as output

Comment: try `print(serializer.errors)` to learn more about serializers read https://learnbatta.com/blog/serializers-in-django-rest-framework-77/ it may help you.

Comment: after running ```print(serializer.errors)``` I am getting following traceback:-  ```AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
[13/Jun/2019 09:40:30] "POST /api/register HTTP/1.1" 500 82857```

Comment: please add traceback

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta added now

Comment: 400 or 500 response ?

Comment: HTTP response which is viewable in "Networking" tab of browser contains this info. `500` is saying that you have broken your code a bit more.

Comment: In order to run ```print(serializer.error)``` I changed from ```createAPIView``` to ```genericAPIView``` and then I got ```HTTP 500```. With ```createAPIView``` it is giving ```HTTP 400``` as seen in network tab.

Comment: And the content of the 400 response is..?

Comment: 400 Response does not have any content however i am getting when i use drf client ```Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `property` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `InterestedUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'InterestedUser' object has no attribute 'property'.```

Comment: I checked in pg Admin and found objects are getting created but still I am getting above error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `property` attribute in your `InterestedUser` model, but a `property_set` instead and that is because you used a `ForeignKey`, thus `InterestedUser <-> Property` is a 1:N relationship.

What can you do?

- Add `related_name=properties` to your `owner` field at `Property`
- At your `UserSerializer`, `property = ReportAPISerializer(source='properties', many=True)`

There are other issues related to how you designed these objects, I would suggest a few things for you to keep in mind:

- If multiple users can be interested in multiuple properties, go for a `ManyToMany`
- Avoid using `property` as the serializer field name, `property` is a reserved python word.